# External 1440p display connected to Intel HD 620 only has 1680x1050 or Full HD as maximum resolutions

Tags: hdmi, resolution, dvi, external-display, usb-c

I want to connect an external screen with 2560x1440 resolution (Dell U2711) to my ThinkPad T470s (LENOVO 20HGS0YK01) with [Intel HD 620](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/96551/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-7th-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-620.html) Graphics and Windows 10. According to the specifications, 2560x1440 should be easily supported. The Monitor supports 1440p via Displayport, and also via **the same DVI-D Dual Link cable as below,** when coming from a different PC.

[The Laptop has HDMI and USB-C outputs.](https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/solutions/pd104681)

An HDMI cable leads to the maximum resolution offered as 1920x1080.

Using the Dual-Link DVI-D cable with a USB-C adapter at the USB-C output gives only a maximum selectable resolution of 1680x1050.

These are both in Windows display settings and also in Intel Graphics Control Center.
The above also holds when I reduce the refresh rate to 24Hz.

Is it possible that the USB-C adapter causes the problem? Are there different USB-C to DVI-D adapters to look out for? After all, the laptop, external screen, and DVI-D cable should support the 1440p-resolution individually.

Comment: Specific model of Thinkpad?

Comment: ThinkPad T470s.

Comment: I have updated some information on the hardware. Is there anything else missing? I could not find a more specific model number than "T470s".

Comment: I didn’t entirely get why you’re not using DisplayPort...?

Comment: The Laptop has no DisplayPort socket. It only has USB-C (beside HDMI), so I have to work with a USB-C-Adapter either way. Since I know that DVI-D Dual Link should be sufficient, there is no reason why I shouldn't get it to work now with DVI, is there? Of course, I can buy a USB-C to DisplayPort adapter, but if I cannot get the current adapter to work, why would I get the next one right?

Comment: USB-C usually offers native DisplayPort connectivity, no active converters required. What you have is an active DisplayPort to DVI converter on top of that. Maybe it’s not even a Dual-Link DVI converter.

Comment: I suspect it is the adapter.